# How to update foreign key with the most recent associated record's id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the most performant way to generate the `latest_entry_id` on checks table from the entries with the same user_id, with the newest start_date that is prior to create_date of the check?

## Before:

### checks table

```
id        |   user_id |  create_date |  latest_entry_id  
------------------------------------------------------
1         |   1       | 2012-01-01   | NULL 
2         |   2       | 2012-01-01   | NULL
```

### entries table

```
id         |   user_id |  start_date 
-------------------------------------
1          |   1       | 2012-02-01         
2          |   1       | 2011-01-01        
3          |   2       | 2011-09-01        
4          |   2       | 2011-10-01
```

## After:

### checks table

```
id        |   user_id |  create_date |  latest_entry_id  
------------------------------------------------------
1         |   1       | 2012-01-01   | 2
2         |   2       | 2012-01-01   | 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The best query I came up with is this

```
Update checks INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT checks.id AS c_id, MAX(entries.start_date) AS max_start_date
    FROM checks LEFT OUTER JOIN entries ON checks.user_id = entries.user_id
    WHERE entries.start_date < checks.create_date
    GROUP BY checks.id
  ) AS tmp
ON checks.id = tmp.c_id
LEFT JOIN entries
ON tmp.max_start_date = entries.start_date AND checks.user_id = entries.user_id
SET checks.latest_entry_id = entries.id
```

This query is performant and avoid running one subquery per check. If you know of another performant way to do this update to get the same results, I would like to hear your way.

Comment: MySQL MAX() function with "GROUP BY" does not give you the id or user_id of the row with the max value. Otherwise, the second join is unnecessary. Do all SQL implementations behave like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can make it work:

```
UPDATE checks c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT e.user_id,
    MAX(e.id) AS ID
  FROM entries e
  INNER JOIN checks c1 ON e.user_id = c1.user_id
    AND e.start_date < c1.create_date
  GROUP BY e.user_id
  ) a ON a.user_id = c.user_id    
SET c.latest_entry_id = a.id;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de27d2/1)</kbd>

p.s. Your second row in your expected results is not consistent with your requirements. latest_entry_id  should be 4, not 3.

Comment: I think you are assuming bigger entries.id means bigger entries.create_date, which is not guaranteed for the problem setup.